# Streamifier error - The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type function ([Function (anonymous)])

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, cloudinary

I am uploading images to cloudinary, and trying to use streamifier so I can read the response in order to get the cloudinary image URL in order to save this to the post collection in MongoDB.

I am using this guide via cloudinarys website - https://cloudinary.com/blog/node_js_file_upload_to_a_local_server_or_to_the_cloud

[This is the response I am trying to receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMEt5.png)

[Backend Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWMbi.png)

Front end code;

```
function NewPost() {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [imagePost, setImagePost] = useState(null);
  console.log(image)
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.currentUser.user);
  const currentUserId = useSelector(
    (state) => state.currentUser.user[0].data.currentUser._id
  );
  console.log("currentUserId: ", currentUserId);
  console.log(user);
  console.log(user[0].data.currentUser.profileImage);
  console.log(image)


  const postAuthor = useSelector((state) => state.currentUser.user);

  const submitFile = async (id) => {
    try {
      let formData = new FormData();

      formData.append("image", image);
      let response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/timeline/${id}/image`, {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST"
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  
  const TargetFile = (e) => {
    if (e.target && e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
      setImagePost(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    try {
      e.preventDefault();
      const post = { videoUrl, content, userId, image };

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/timeline/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(post),
      })
      if (response.ok) {
        window.location.reload(false);
  
      }
      
      if (TargetFile) {
        let res = await response.json();
        await submitFile(res.file);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
```

[And the error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1bbd.png)

Before the error I was getting was 'must be of type String, Object or Uni8Array', no changes yet a different error message, really need help.

If I haven't included something, please reply and let me know. A lot of unanswered questions on stack overflow for some reason. Please let me know why.

EDIT - LATEST ERROR MESSAGE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dVqp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Cloudinary documentation you linked, the method they indicate to upload a file is `cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream` while your backend code uses `cloudinary.uploader.upload`.

`upload_stream` apparently takes a callback function as argument but `upload` must accept a string representing the path of the image (if I read the error message correctly).

Note that using the stacktrace, you can see that the error comes from the line 65 of your `src/routes/posts/index.js` file. That's a good starting point for the analysis next time... :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had changed it from upload_stream to upload to test what the result was, I have now changed it back to upload_steam and I am getting the original error I was talking about TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined'

Is it maybe to do with how I am defining the image in the schema? I have tried setting it to String, Buffer, Object, all give same error

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the most recent error message at the end of the post :)

Comment: You should re-read the Cloudinary documentation. Your code is incorrect: you are passing `req.file` to the `streamUpload` method and in the method implementation, you are doing again `req.file` instead of `req.buffer`

Answer (score 0):

That blog may be out of date as if you go to Cloudinary's official Node.js page, streamifier is no longer relevant.

See: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload#node_js_image_upload

I would recommend try and set up per https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#installation_and_setup and use

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("/home/my_image.jpg", 
    function(error, result) {console.log(result, error)});
```